# window.innerWidth does not return the real floating point width

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

In latest-version chrome, I get two different heights for the viewport, one of them truncated into an integer, and the other probably the correct one:

`window.innerWidth`: 757

`Chrome dev tools`: 757.778

It may seem that for pixel perfect svg, I'd need to use the floating point number for more "pixel perfect" results.

How can I programmatically get the full floating point value in Javascript?

Comment: Instead, is it `window.outerWidth` that is returning the decimal? Give it a shot. Hopefully this will help!

Comment: window.outerWidth is not working for me. Any changes you still remember how to get the floating value? tks

Comment: Got a float using : `window.visualViewport.height`

Comment: Thanks for this. Was using `window.innerWidth` and Height to resize my canvas and it was leaving black edges when the browser was zoomed in and out. Now I'm using `Math.ceil(window.visualViewport.width)` (and height) and now the canvas is filling the entire window.inner on resize!

Comment: @Fusei awesome, you save my day :D